Lubricate between spoke nipples and carbon rim?
When building wheels, nipples should be lubricated so they can still turn easily under tension, towards the end of the build.
When building a wheel using carbon rims, do you also lubricate the contact area between rim and underside of nipples?
Do I have to use special lubricate on carbon rims?

I’d still use grease or other lubrication for the same reasons.

Its normal to grease or prep the spoke thread which eases turning the nipple.  You're asking specifically about greasing the underside of the nipple head where it presses on the carbon of the rim, right ?

That's right @Criggie, I'm asking about greasing the underside of the nipple head, where it touches the carbon of the rim.
